# Cypress using JSON fixture in body?

Tags: cypress

So based off Cypress request docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html

It seems like I should be able to send a POST request with a JSON body pretty easily. So this is what I tried:

```
cy.fixture('test_create').as('create_test')
cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/widgets',
  body: '@create_test',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': this.token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
  }
})
```

However when I look at the "commands" Cypress sends, it's sending the body as literally `Body: @create_test`

Is it not possible to use a fixture within the body of a POST request? I confirmed the fixture is loading correctly. I confirmed also it works when I paste the entire JSON inside of the `body` option....but that gets ugly really quick with large JSON bodys.

Comment: You have told it that the body should be passed a string: `'@create_test'` - did you really mean: `body: @create_test`

Comment: @Mikkel for whatever reason that gives me an error when I try to refer to it just as `@create_test`

Comment: @Mikkel Looks like the issue might've had to do with fixture being async and my request happening before the fixture was loaded? Once I added a `then` and handled the request within that `then` everything worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a literal because in the form `cy.request(options)`, options is a plain JS object and unfortunately not parsed by Cypress to interpret the alias.

The request form `cy.request(method, url, body)` probably does allow an alias for the body param, since `cy.route()` allows it [ref: Accessing Fixture Data](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Accessing-Fixture-Data)

e.g the following should be valid, but does not allow setting headers

```js
cy.fixture('test_create').as('create_test')
cy.request('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/widgets', '@create_test');
```

So, you can use `then()`

```js
cy.fixture('test_create').then(myFixture => {

  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/widgets',
    body: myFixture,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': this.token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
  })
});
```

or

```js
cy.fixture('test_create').as('create_test');

...  // some other code between

cy.get('@create_test').then(myFixture => {  // retrieve the fixture from alias

  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/widgets',
    body: myFixture,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': this.token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: I ended up having to use `then()` the other thing is that `cy.fixture()` is async. So my thinking was also that using `this.fixturename` may not have been "read" yet. So by using `then()` I made sure not to do the request till after the fixture was done loading.

Comment: I noticed the comment that you already had the answer after I posted, but it's useful for others to see some explicit code.

Comment: As for fixture being async, I wonder if that's correct? I understand `cy.fixture()` to be shorthand for 'read this file from the fixtures folder', which does not have to be done async. Note that `.then()` looks like a promise then, but it's not really - it just gives you access to the previous command result.

Comment: Using local variables like `this.fixturename` does work, but is gets tricky because `this` can change depending on whether you use `function` style `it()` or arrow functions, so I personally prefer to use `then()`.